# create databases and tables dynamically with Yii framework possible?

Tags: yii

I am developing a system with a master database and multiple databases, once for each client. The client database and its tables will be created when the client fills in and submit a form with all the required details.

My question: does the Yii framework support the dynamic creation of databases and tables? If so, is there any example code? (I'm still learning about Yii) I couldnt find an answer on the Yii website (documentation and forum) nor on this site. (I did notice that dynamic databse connections are possibble with Yii - [Yii Dynamic DB Connection according to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684218/yii-dynamic-db-connection-according-to-user))

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36952-saas-multi-tenant-separate-db/

Comment: thnx for that. In your link mr seenivasan responds: "....Then we create a separate database on his name." And that's where I would be interested to see some example code how to create the DB. I know how to create a DB and tables by means of PHP. I also understand the concept of Yii to create a DB and tables using the commandtools and then have the model generated automatically by the Gii tool. But how to create the database and table and related models dynamically? Can one still somehow call Gii via controller to generate the model?

Comment: Yii relies on database already configured. I assume you need something like install script and it's a good idea to do it the good old way.

Comment: I guess you mean using plain php (?) At the yii forumsite they also told me its very hard to do with Yii. Which I think is a pity as I started to like the Yii concept requiring less and simpler code...

Answer (score 0):

For connections in runtime read [php-yii-database-connect-in-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428597/php-yii-database-connect-in-runtime) and after that, Yii have all Building Schema Manipulation Queries like CREATE, ALTER, DROP etc.
So easy and simple.
[building-schema-manipulation-queries](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#building-schema-manipulation-queries)